# Clojure 1.6.0 error: Could not locate clojure/core/logic__init.class

Tags: java, eclipse, counterclockwise

I am using Clojure 1.6.0 and I get this error:

> CompilerException java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not locate clojure/core/logic__init.class or clojure/core/logic.clj on classpath: ,
>   compiling:(hello\core.clj:8:70)

Answer (score 0):

Add `[org.clojure/core.logic "1.0.0"]` to your leiningen dependencies. See https://github.com/clojure/core.logic for more information.